# What is the most convinient approach of updating an object in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following redux state structure:

```
initState = {
    section1: {
        field1: true,
        field2: "asdfg"
    },
    section2: {
      ....
    },
    ....  
};
```

Every field in section is input on UI.

What is better approach to update state:

```
[actions.setSection1]: (state, section1) => {
    return {...state, section1}
}
```

or

```
[actions.setField1]: (state, field1) => {
    return {...state, section1: {...state.section1, field1}}
}
```

I prefer the second one, but after input is changed I need to send section to the server. So I'll need to implement something like {...section1, field1} in my component anyway to send the latest object. That's why it looks better to form object in component and update the whole section in redux.

Didn't found what is the best practice in this situation.
How do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The first option will update the whole section, losing the data it held before. The second option will be a partial update to the section, only updating the necessary information.

Because the second option is more fine-grained, it leaves less risk for unintended loss of data that could occur if the calling function made unknown changes to the section before dispatching.

Comment: in first case action will be dispatched like: setSection1({...section1, field1}), so data should not be losed.

Comment: The only argument to this approach is that in component I will need to do something like this.saveChanges({...section1, field1}) after calling specific action anyway